# Angular.js How do I use location.search in app.config?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false); except if a query param of ?debug=true is passed into the url. However $location does not work in the app.config function.

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', '$location',
function ($compileProvider, $location) {

    if (!$location.search().debug || $location.search().debug === false) {
        $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
    }
}
]);
```

I get an error 'Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $location'

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.

$location is a service, and has no provider. The only way to get to the underlying browser's location object is directly. You can use $window to help with unit testing, if you need that:

```
if (!$window.location.search.debug || $window.location.search.debug === false) {
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only inject providers and constants in to the configuration block.Instead of using `$location` in config try to use it in `.run()` or use `$locationProvider` instead.

Comment: $locationProvider doesn't give access to the browser's location object - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: yes @bbrown you are right. I meant instead you wanted $locationProvider :D